# Why is XCode`s LLVM GCC 4.2 compiler failing to generate correct assembly?

Tags: ios, xcode, compiler-construction, compilation

I'm using XCode 4.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and running the iOS5 emulator.
I have a workspace with a main project, and a secondary project that the main is dependent on.

My problem is, after I make change to a .cpp or .mm file in the secondary project, even though XCode recompiles the appropriate files, it does not generate new assembly code reflecting the code change.  Thus when stepping over my code in the debugger, stepping to the next line skips any changes I have made.
My only recourse is do a clean and a build.

The main project can be compiled with either LLVM GCC 4.2 or Apple LLVM Compiler 3.0.
However, (due to what I think are unreasonable compile errors regarding templated classes calling functions of parent classes) I can only compile the secondary project with LLVM GCC 4.2.

Both projects contain objective c files, though the secondary project is largely an existing c++ codebase being reused on iOS.

Thanks in advance for any guidance to resolving this.

---

*Example behavior:*

**regular build:** 
During debugging, imagine stepping over 3 lines of code.  The 1st line is old code that has been compiled many times.  The 2nd and 3rd lines were just typed and compiled w/o doing a clean + build.  When the program counter is at the 1st line of code, the compiler thinks that all 3 lines of code are really one and is highlighting them all together to indicate the currently executing line. Stepping to the next line skips lines 2 and 3 and moves the program counter to the next valid line of code, i.e. line 4.

**clean + build:**
This time the debugger behaves as expected.  When the program counter is at line 1, only it is highlighted.  Stepping to the next line moves the program counter to line 2.

---

Since I can edit the main project's source and debug fine, perhaps my problem is that I have not properly specified the dependency between the two projects.
In the main project's Target->Build Phases->Target Dependencies, Ive set a dependency to be the output of the subproject.
Also in Xcode's project navigator (view via command 1 shortcut), you can see that the sub-project is physically contained inside the main project.